# Replace the second char of a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string variable.

```
Dim str As String = "ABBCD"
```

I want to replace **only the second** 'B' character of str (I mean the second occurrence)

my code

```
Dim regex As New Regex("B")
Dim result As String = regex.Replace(str, "x", 2)

'result: AxxCD
'but I want: ABxCD
```

What's the easiest way to do this with Regular Expressions.

thanks

Comment: `ABCABCABC => ABCAxCABC` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim str As String = "ABBCD"
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(str, "B")
    If matches.Count >= 2 Then
        str = str.Remove(matches(1).Index, matches(1).Length)
        str = str.Insert(matches(1).Index, "x")
    End If
```

First we declare the string 'str', then find the matches of "B". If we found two results or more, replace the second result with "x".

Comment: Please add some commentary to your answers to explain why this code solves the problem. Code-only answers are often not very useful for beginners.

Comment: Okay, first we declare the string 'str'
Then find the matches of "B"
If we found two results or more, replace the second result with "x"

Comment: Edit your answer with the commentary.

Comment: that's what I really want to do. I just want to replace only the second "B" (not, after second or last "B") and also can adjustable such as third "B" or fourth etc. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(B)\1", "$+x");
```

Comment: Also try to post an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookbehind:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("(?<=B)B")
```

[**Live demo**](https://ideone.com/0Q8fd0)

Answer (score 1):

If `ABCABCABC` should produce `ABCAxCABC`, then the following regex will work:

```
(?<=^[^B]*B[^B]*)B
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Usage:

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=^[^B]*B[^B]*)B", "x")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `BB` was just an example, it can be `CC`, `DD`, `EE`, etc..
Based on that, the regex below will replace any repeated character in the string.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\w)\1", "$1x");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Alternative way to replace the second occurrence
    'only of B in the string with X
    Dim str As String = "ABBCD"
    Dim pattern As String = "B"
    Dim reg As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
    Dim replacement As String = "X"
    'find position of second B
    Dim secondBpos As Integer = Regex.Matches(str, pattern)(1).Index
    'replace that B with X
    Dim result As String = reg.Replace(str, replacement, 1, secondBpos)
    MessageBox.Show(result)
```